# Not able to find Coded UI .trx result files

Tags: browser-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI in VSTS 2013 for creating automated tests using Coded UI Test Builder. I am able to create tests successfully but not able to view their result files. I found that there is a folder **TestResults** at the project location but it contains only images. I am not able to find the `.trx` files for the test results.

Also, I tried using the below settings for saving the result files to a different location, this works but as soon as the test case execution is over, test result folders created at this location disappears. In addition to it I am not able to find anything related to this execution in the **Test Results** window, only **Test Explorer** window shows the progress and execution result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>C:\Dhiman\CUITTestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

I have used the following links for the reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj635153.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754354/vs2012-unit-tests-how-to-change-the-location-of-the-testresults-folder

I need the `.trx` files so that I can create HTML report from them using the [trx2html](http://trx2html.codeplex.com/) application.

Comment: fyi trx2html only claims to support up to VS2012, and not 2013

Comment: Did you saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245597/mstest-how-to-prevent-custom-log-file-from-being-deleted-and-prevent-trx-from or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/638a4b94-26bf-464c-b933-5979b06adb33/visual-studio-mstest-logs-are-being-automatically-deleted?forum=vstest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run my Coded UI tests from the commandline with `/Logger:trx` this generates a .trx file

```
vstest.console.exe "MyApp\Debug\MyApp.CodedUI.Test.dll" /tests:TestCase1,TestCase2 /Logger:trx
```

You find the vstest.console.exe in your VS directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\`

Comment: I tried the same and getting this error "Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v
1': Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\ID
E\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\TestResults\Deploy_adhiman 2015-11-23 11
_59_39' is denied.". I don't have administrators right, Do I need to have those for running it?

Comment: Not really just add the TestWindow directory to your path and run the vstest.console.exe from the source directory or any other directory you have write access in

Comment: It worked for me but I changed your solution a bit, I used .runsettings file and provided the path of the test results in that file. This path was the one where I have write permissions. But at last your solution solved my issue.

Comment: So there's no way to generate the .TRX programmaticaly? Man...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we couldn’t get the .trx file when we run the coded UI test in the VS 2012 IDE now, one solution is that you could run it in [command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182488.aspx) eg.

```
MSTest /testmetadata:Bank.vsmdi /resultsfile:BanktestResults.trx
```